# How do I escape many $ signs in a large string in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a large string containing Javascript code that I want to write to a file. The problem is that it has many $ signs and the compiler is treating it as string interpolation.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings - most likely "raw" string will help

Answer (score 1):

Use ***r*** in front of the string to denote it is a raw string.

```
String codeJS =r'''var idMatch = /^#[\w-]*$/,
      classMatch = /^\.[\w-]*$/,
      htmlMatch = /<.+>/,
      singlet = /^\w+$/;''';
```